# iterating over array inside "select" helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have selector in edit form which should assing User to Project.

```
= f.label :user_id
= f.select(:user_id, [['First user', 1], ['Second user', 2]])
```

Now it's with sample data.

User model should parse user.name and user.id of each existed user in the selector. That way I'll be able to assign required user to project

For now I have

```
- User.all.each do |user|
  = f.select(:user_id, [[user.name, user.id]])
```

But it just creates separate selector for each User.
But I need to create a list of existed users in one selector. Which is the best way to display results of iteration over users? I guess there should be `%li` tag but I can't figure out how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `f.select` as you wish you could use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
= f.select(:user_id, User.pluck(:name, :id))
```

`User.pluck(:name, :id)` creates an array of `[name, id]` tuples.

Comment: You answer fits me better) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can use [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) helper:

```
f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :name)
```